Salesforce SOQL Query for several user ContentDocuments
I am trying to write a SOQL query to retrieve some Salesforce ContentDocument but it seems I am restricted to documents I created myself.
I cannot see ContentDocument from other users even with the System Administrator profile.
Is there a way to get around this ? What permission should I give to solve this problem ?

You need the Query All Files permission.

Here is the quick solution for this :
"Go to Set Up => Permission Set => Choose an existing or create a new Permission set => Click App Permissions => Click Edit => Content => Check the "Query All Files"  => Click Manage Assignments =>  Add Assignments => Check all Users you want to add.
By default, it is disabled for the System admin user also but you can enable it in the Permissions Set.
Here is the Salesforce Help link for more details.
It is also documented in the Salesforce Developer Docs.
Thank You!
